# One ip with multiple ports

Tags: php, sockets, networking, socket.io

In my test environment I have a setup using our public IP. Is it possible to have multiple ports to listen on one public IP?

The reason for this Question is, I have two services to be run:

- My php socket is already bind to our public ip and 1 port
- Now I have another service (the socket.io). Do I need to open another port to bind it to our public IP intended for this socket.io?

Comment: Yes, having multiple ports to connect to is not only possible, it's why ports exist in the first place.

Comment: @Amadan, sorry but can you clear it up for me,it is not possible?

Comment: It is very possible. You might as well ask if you were permitted to eat with a  fork and a knife at the same time. :)